# webrtc is not working on azure hsoting

Tags: azure, signalr, webrtc

i am doing video conferencing in webrtc. and chat application in signalR. the video conferencing is working locally but when i host the application the conferencing on azure it is not working but signalR chat App is working properly. suggest me another hosting site for webrtc applications.

Comment: off topic for stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

are you using https? Chrome only allows getUserMedia for secure origins with an exception for localhost.